# Example Chef HTTP GET/POST Cookbook

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm learning chef and need a really simple barebones cookbook/recipe example that can call an external HTTP API (GET/POST) and put the contents into a file. I've looked through the community cookbooks but they all seem to be overkill for learning and trying to understand whats happening and naturally most seem to be focussed on installing packages. Does anybody have anything I can use here :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `remote_file` resource for your needs, like:

```
remote_file "/tmp/testfile" do
  source "http://www.example.com/tempfiles/testfile"
  mode '0644'
  checksum "3a7dac00b1" # A SHA256 (or portion thereof) of the file.
end
```

- **"/tmp/testfile"** - location where file will be saved
- **"http://www.example.com/tempfiles/testfile"** - source location
- **"checksum"** and **"mode"** - optional but it's recommendable

---

You can see it in action from [nginx community cookbook](https://github.com/miketheman/nginx):

```
nginx_url = node['nginx']['source']['url'] ||
        "http://nginx.org/download/nginx-#{node['nginx']['source']['version']}.tar.gz"

src_filepath  = "#{Chef::Config['file_cache_path'] || '/tmp'}/nginx-#{node['nginx']['source']['version']}.tar.gz"

....

remote_file nginx_url do
  source   nginx_url
  checksum node['nginx']['source']['checksum']
  path     src_filepath
  backup   false
end
```

More info about this built in resource you can [find here](https://docs.chef.io/resource_remote_file.html).

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it would be to send requests and handle the response in a  ruby_block using the 'net/http'module in ruby .For mode information refer  : http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/HTTP.html